# Outputting a project's .class files to another project's resources folder in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently developing a 2 project system, `mainProj` and `sideProj`.

The idea would be to have the output .class files from `sideProj` be put as `mainProj`'s resource files, so I'd like to find a way to automatically put the output os `sideProj` as resources of `mainProj`.

The "default output folder" option only seems to allow me to output to any directory inside a given project, not to other projects.

What would be the best way to accomplish this (preferably without having to resort to ant)?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it easier the other way around by simply adding sideProj to the build path of mainProj? Like for every normal library project and main project? Or is there a more specific reason for moving those class files?

If you really want to process as described initially, an Ant based builder is probably your only choice (select sideProj, context menu, properties, builders, add, Ant, ...). While you have to write that short script yourself, it takes part in the automatic build process afterwards without you needing to invoke it.

Comment: I'd prefer to stay away from Ant if possible, as it would require a full build every time I did some change in any one of the projects (i.e., I couldn't make use of automatic building), but I'll eventually have to stick to that if there is no other way around.